# Output missing values from one array/dataframe versus another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, duplicates

I'm not sure whether the following is easier in pandas or numpy so I'll leave that to the answers.

I'd like to compare two arrays / dataframes which are both single rows of string data. I'd like to output the values that appear in arr2 but DON'T appear in arr1. For example

```
arr1 = np.array(['fish','bear','cat'])
arr2 = np.array(['fish','bear','dog'])

output = ['dog']
```

The output would be dog since dog doesn't appear in arr1.

Comment: You mentioned that you want to output the values that don't appear in both. From the example you've provided that will be dog _and_ cat.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to output the values that appear in `arr2` but not `arr1`?

Comment: yes correct, the values that appear in arr2 but NOT arr1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a 'set difference'. `numpy` has a somewhat aptly named function for this behaviour `setdiff1d` (see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array(['fish','bear','cat'])
arr2 = np.array(['fish','bear','dog'])

output = np.setdiff1d(arr2, arr1)
```

`output` will contain a `numpy` array with the singular value of 'dog':

```
array(['dog'], dtype='<U4')
```

To convert this to a list, simply use the `tolist` method:

```
output = np.setdiff1d(arr2, arr1).tolist()

['dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
```

Make use of [`np.isin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) method:

```
arr2[~np.isin(arr2,arr1)]

#output
array(['dog'], dtype='<U4')
```

And If you want exact same output that you mention in your question then chain `tolist()` method on the above code:

```
arr2[~np.isin(arr2,arr1)].tolist()

#output
['dog']
```

Comment: I like this answer, since the OP mentioned a dataframe and the same syntax can be used for numpy or pandas

Comment: needs to be modified to remove NaNs for pandas i think.

Comment: just chain `dropna()` method for removing NaNs in pandas